# Buffer overflow and register contents?

Tags: attacks, buffer-overflow, shellcode, aslr, dep

I am doing an exam practice question, suppose I have a function like;

```
void func(char* arg)
{
     char buf[32];
     strcpy(buf, arg);
}

command break func:
-buf begins at 0xbffebfb0
-(gdb) x/2wx $ebp
 0xbfebfd8: 0xbffec068  0x08048fe1
 machine is 32 bit little endian, no defenses like aslr or dep
```

> c) You want to run a payload/shellcode that is 24 bytes long,write hex
>   bytes that should be copied into the buffer for an overflow exploit? *I
>   don't really know how to go about creating buffer overflows.*

However I would want to write in '\x90', but I don't know how much to write and where it lands you

> d) Assuming ASLR is enabled, which results in stack being offset by
>   0-15 each time it runs. Describe a payload in form of a python print
>   statement that will always get the shellcode from part c to execute? (
>   assume, stack condition from part c holds when offset is 0).

I think the print statement would look like python below;

```
print shellcode + '\bytes filled in' + pack("<I", shellcode_addr) + pack("<I", return_addr)
```

But I can't do much on part d without knowing part c, I need some help on how I would solve such c and d.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82750/why-are-buffer-overflows-executed-in-the-direction-they-are/82846#82846).